# Dependency Analysis Error in XCode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I'm trying to run a project developed in iOS 7.1 in xcode 6.

I get the error:

```
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386).
```

[image]